# What is the adjective for someone who pretends?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here's the sentence: He's pretending that he didn't know anything. He is _____.

What is the ***adjective*** for someone who pretends? *Pretender* is a *noun*. Is it **pretentious**? But the meaning of it is:

---

**pretentious** */pri-ˈten(t)-shəs/*

*adjective*

1:  characterized by pretension: such as

- making usually unjustified or excessive claims (as of value or
  standing)

  > the pretentious fraud who assumes a love of culture that is alien to 
  >   him — *Richard Watts*
- expressive of affected, unwarranted, or exaggerated importance, worth, or stature

  > pretentious language pretentious houses

2
:  making demands on one's skill, ability, or means :  ambitious

> the pretentious daring of the Green Mountain Boys in crossing the lake — *Amer. Guide Series: Vt.*

**pretentiously** *adverb*

**pretentiousness** *noun*

*Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious*

Comment: There is possibly an entry in OED licensing 'pretentious' as 'involved in an act / stance of pretence', but even if this were the case, the other senses would so eclipse this that it would be best avoided.  I'd prefer a work-around to anything I've thought of so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Feign**
>   [feyn]/ 
>   verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to represent fictitiously; put on an appearance of:
>      to feign sickness.
> 2. to invent fictitiously or deceptively, as a story or an excuse.
> 3. to imitate deceptively:
>      to feign another's voice.
>
> verb (used without object)
>
> 4. to make believe; pretend:
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/feigning)

He's pretending that he didn't know anything. He is *feigning ignorance*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *pretending*. It follows from the rest of the sentence whether this is a verb or an adjective.
The OED has a separate entry for this:

> **pretending, *adj***.
>
> That pretends (in various senses); pretentious. Also, of a thing or
> action: imitative, imaginary; involving pretence or imitation.
> [...]
>
> *1681   W. Temple Mem. iii, in Wks. (1731) I. 334*: The pretending Knowers among them,..pretended now to know nothing of it.

So if your whole sentence is "he is pretending", it would be regarded a verb, whereas if you say "the pretending dog faked being wounded", it would be used as an adjective.

Answer (score -1):

It's still *pretend*, though it tends to colour the sentence with the 'make-believe' sense of pretend, as opposed to the 'hoax' sense.

> **pretend** *adjective (informal)*
>   Not really what it is represented as being; imaginary.
>   ‘You just become someone walking around in freedom, no longer a pretend celebrity with a wallet to be taxed.’
>   [– ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pretend)

Comment: This is the sentence: He's pretending that he didn't know anything. He is _____.

Comment: @Fawkes You should have put that in your question, and I should have waited for you to do so. Anyway, you might say that he is "a *pretend* ignoramus".

Comment: @Lawrence I think that this usage makes it part of a compound statement, where 'pretend' is not an adjective to the subject of the sentence, but part of the predicate.

Comment: @HenryJekyll1886 The technicalities of linguistics isn't my strong suit, but I think the case is stronger for *pretend* to be a straight-out adjective in my example, as opposed to a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) or similar, such as with *chicken* in "chicken soup".